# How can I avoid a gazillion database queries with related doctrine entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

On the profiler toolbar I noticed a lot of db queries, 400+, this happens when I print a related entity info. I am very new to setting doctrine mapping information within my entities so I don't know whether it's something I have misconfigured or if that's the way it is or maybe there is a better way to do it.

Basically the **Estimates** entity has two one-to-one relations to the **CustomersHomes** entity. I'll post my code, maybe you can spot something or perhaps you could tell me if my code so far is going in the right direction.

The **Estimates** class:

```
class Estimates
{
...
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MG\AdminBundle\Entity\CustomersHomes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="work_address_id", referencedColumnName="homes_id")
 *
 */
private $workAddress;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MG\AdminBundle\Entity\CustomersHomes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="homes_id", referencedColumnName="homes_id")
 *
 */
private $homeAddress;

...

// getters and setters are in place below

...

}
```

And here is the action method in the CustomersController.php

```
public function viewAction($customersId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $customer = $em->getRepository('MGAdminBundle:Customers')->find($customersId);
    if (!$customer){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->get('translator')->trans('No record found for this customer.'));
    }

    $allHomes = $em->getRepository('MGAdminBundle:CustomersHomes')->getHomes($customersId,null,10);
    $billingHomes = $em->getRepository('MGAdminBundle:CustomersHomes')->getHomes($customersId, 'billing', 2);
    $allHomesCount = $em->getRepository('MGAdminBundle:CustomersHomes')->getHomesCountByCustomer($customersId);
    $customerSecondaryEmails = $customer->getEmails();
    $customerMessages = $customer->getMessages();
    $estimateRequests = $customer->getRequests();
    $estimates = $customer->getEstimates();
    return $this->render('MGAdminBundle:Customers:view.html.twig', array(
            'customer' => $customer,
            'allHomes' => $allHomes,
            'billingHomes' => $billingHomes,
            'allHomesCount' => $allHomesCount,
            'customerSecondaryEmails' => $customerSecondaryEmails,
            'messages' => $customerMessages,
            'estimateRequests' => $estimateRequests,
            'estimates' => $estimates,
            ));
}
```

Here is MGAdminBundle:Customers:view.html.twig

```
{% extends 'MGAdminBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title 'Profile: ' | trans ~ customer.firstname | upper ~ ' ' ~ customer.lastname | upper %}
{% block content %}
    {% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_customer-details.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_secondary-contacts.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_addresses.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_estimate-requests.html.twig' %}    
    {% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_messages.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_estimates.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here is MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_estimates.html.twig

```
{% if estimates|length > 0 %}
    <h3>{{ 'Estimates' | trans }}</h3>
    <fieldset>

    {% for estimate in estimates %}        
        <div class="row {{ cycle(['even','odd'],loop.index) }}">
            <div class="col-sm-1">{{ estimate.estimatesId | default('-') }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">{% include 'MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_estimate-address.html.twig' with {'homeAddress': estimate.homeAddress, 'workAddress': estimate.workAddress} %}</div>            
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">{{ estimate.total }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">{{ estimate.status | default('-') }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">payments</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">options</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
{% endif %}
```

And finally the partial to print the estimate address: MGAdminBundle:Customers/Partials:_estimate-address.html.twig (I'm still working with this template)

```
{% if homeAddress is defined %}

    {{ homeAddress.name }}

{% endif %}

{% if workAddress is defined %}

    {{ workAddress.name }}

{% endif %}
```

And here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

**Questions:**

- What is the best strategy to get the home address and work address of each estimate?
- Should the estimates that belong to a customer be fetched from a repository method? Right now the estimates are gotten using a getter inside the customer entity.

Please bear with me, I'm new to all of this and I don't even know If I make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Doctrine you can find all estimates using..

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                            ->getRepository('MGAdminBundle:Customers');
```

Either...

```
$estimates = $repository->findAll();
// Find all estimates on DB
```

Or...

```
$estimates = $repository->findBy(array(
    'constraint1' => 'blah1',
    'constraint2' => 'blah2',
));
// Find all estimates that fit constraints
// Constraints can take object if they are associations
```

From there the whole tree is available. So..

```
foreach ($estimates as $estimate) {
    $things = $estimate->getThings();
    foreach ($things as $thing) {
       .. something with $thing ..
    }
}
```

Or with twig..

```
return $this->render('MGAdminBundle:Estimates:view.html.twig', array(
        'estimates' => $estimates,
    );
```

then actual twig..

```
{% for estimate in estimates %}
    {% for thing in estimate.things %}
        .. something with {{ thing }} ..
    {% else %}
        No things // Twig has a nice incorporated for, else thing
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    No estimates
{% endfor %}
```